# Почему происходит ошибка "cannot access jakarta.servlet.ServletException class file"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Выдает такую ошибку:

> java: cannot access jakarta.servlet.ServletException class file for jakarta.servlet.ServletException not found

Все `dependency` написаны.

Вот мои `dependencies`:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Вот мой класс:

```
package ru.example.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMVCDispatcherSerlvetInitialazier extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка указывает на то, что компилятор Java не может найти класса jakarta.servlet.ServletException.
Нужно добавить зависимость для Jakarta EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы используете Apache Tomcat версии 10+.

В любом случае в Dependecies у Вас прописана зависимость для javax, в то время как проект хочет использовать jackarta.

Поменяйте:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

На:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Версию в Jackarta установите актуальную на вашу дату.

Актуальную версию можно посмотреть [ТУТ](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/).